# Render HTML as string from Rails ERB template, no unicode characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, unicode, encoding

I have the snippet below that runs without errors, however, it returns unicode characters in the response:

```
if params[:template] == 'Application Acknowledgement'
  render json: { :template => render_to_string(:template => "template.erb") }
end
```

The ERB sends back the HTML template with the dynamic content, but the below HTML looks like this:

HTML in template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
</html>
```

HTML returned by the above snippet:

```
\u003c!doctypehtml\u003e\n\u003chtml\u003e\n\t\u003chead\u003e
```

How can I return normal UTF-8 HTML from the controller as a string in Rails?

---

**Addition**

The problem lies in converting unicode string to json e.g.:

```
"абв".to_json
```

becomes

```
"\"\\u0410\\u0411\\u0412\""
```

Whereas `JSON::dump('АБВ')` returns `"\"АБВ\""`, every single one of unicode characters passed to `render json:` becomes escaped.

How to avoid escaping unicode symbols in rendering json?

Comment: Why do you render it as json?

Comment: Because there's other data rendered back to the client in addition to the HTML.

Comment: I just didn't include it in the question as it's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: It works with render template, but I need to send back extra data to the client outside of just the template.

Comment: Seems that problem lies in [encoding non ascii character in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268289/how-to-get-rid-of-non-ascii-characters-in-ruby). There is another good answer to [json encoding question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123993/json-encoding-wrongly-escaped-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2)

Comment: The question should be about converting unicode string to json. May I edit your question?

Comment: Also (rails uft 8 response)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342552/rails-utf-8-response] question might be useful